Methods of convergence in GW-BSE calculations: Quantum ESPRESSO and BerkleyGW
I have been learning BSE calculation through Quantum ESPRESSO and BerkeleyGW. I have been successful to obtain the silicon optical spectra (via GW-BSE), as instructed in the tutorial. The values of the parameters were same as in the tutorial example. However, I am kind of confused about the convergence.
Which parameter need to converge? It would be great to see the step by step procedure. Any plotting command to test the convergence criteria will also be appreciated.

Have you found your answer? If yes, would you please you share it?

I have not received any other reply yet. @MuhammadHasan

you need to converge:

The number of unoccupied bands used in the summation in computing the dielectric matrix and the Coulomb-hole summation for the self-energy (convergence can be tested for a single quasiparticle energy with a ~2x2x2 k-grid)

The density of the two k-point grids used: the coarse grid for the dielectric matrix, quasiparticle energies, and BSE kernel, and the fine grid onto which the BSE kernel is interpolated in absorption

The screened Coulomb cutoff (G-vector cutoff) used for computing the dielectric matrix and the Coulomb-hole summation for the self-energy


I paste here a rigorous procedure highlighted in these slides by a former BerkeleyGW developer:

Calculate the dielectric matrix with “infinite” number of
empty states and G-vectors, test error in QP gaps as you
vary number of bands used in CH summation

Test error as you vary the number of G-vectors in your
dielectric matrix while using an infinite number of empty
states and and infinite number of bands in CH summation

Test error as you vary the number of empty states used in
dielectric matrix while using an infinite number of g-vectors
and an infinite number of bands in the CH summation


In the BerkeleyGW tutorial workshop files, there is also an example (4b-MoS2) that uses the BGWPy Python package (a workflow managing tool) to set up some of these convergence tests automatically.
